# Write a dictionary to a file containing TOML-formatted data with Japanese

Tags: python, toml

Here is a test.py script Write a dictionary to a file containing TOML-formatted data:

```
def createtoml(path):
    dst_file = "config.toml"
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = {
        'download':{
            'path':path
            }
    with open(dst_file, 'w') as f:
        r = toml.dump(a, f)

name=input('Name:')
path="F:\\\\"+name
createtoml(path)
```

If the input of name is Japanese or Chinese, such as まひろ, the TOML-formatted data would be:
    
    `[download]
    serial = ""
    path = "F:\\\\"`

How do the TOML-formatted data be shown in Japanese or Chinese, like `path = "F:\\\\まひろ"`?

Comment: Have you tried passing `encoding="utf-8"` to `open`? By default `open` will use an encoding it infers from he system, which is rarely what you want. Incidentally your `if __name__ == '__main__'`makes essentially no sense, this is a stanza for not executing code on import, it's for the toplevel of the file not to randomly sprinkle into functions.

Comment: I have not tried passing encoding="utf-8" to open. I  have decode config.toml by Notepad++ to utf-8. The output is F:\\\\ƢƖƱ.

Comment: An error message is shown by passing encoding="utf-8" to open:
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 39: invalid continuation byte

Comment: You need to trash the existing file, it's using whatever garbage `sys.getdefaultencoding(False)` is on your system. And you need to sed the encoding on every `open` call.

Comment: The .toml can be open if all the content in .toml is in English, but cannot be open in Japanese with error: `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 39: invalid continuation byte`. Is it related to trash the existing file?

Comment: Possibly, I really have no idea. Again I recommend checking what `sys.getdefaultencoding(False)` is on your system, that's the encoding `open` uses when in text mode and nothing is specified. Or use `file` on your toml to try and see what encoding it's in.